# Best methodology for file uploading (how does YouTube do it?)

Tags: file, uploading

What is the best method to follow for uploading files to server using my website? Each user will upload some files to his profile. Should I place all files in a single directory or do I need to create folders for each user and keep the files there?

How does YouTube do this? How should I store the uploaded info in database? What's the most efficient approach to do this when handling large number of users and files? I don't want to know about the usage of API. I want to know the best approach for file organization.

Comment: What type of hosting are you on and with who?

Answer (score 1):

I would have a folder for each user, its more managable!

I wouldn't fancy a massive folder with loads of files!

You could end up with duplicate file names and end up deleting another users files!

I would create a directory for every user!

Comment: What should be the ideal way to name the folder.Id or User's Name ?

Comment: You should also group the users into subfolders - when you get 100,000+ users you'll be glad you did

Comment: Group on what basis ?I have only one type of users

Comment: First few characters of username/ID is one possibility.

Comment: you could group them by date, alphabetically (first letter of username)! if you end up with lots of users it will save you hassle down the line